# Can We Create SharePoint Custom Web Parts in Office 365 Online with out using Visual Studio?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, office365

I am new to SharePoint and Exploring the Office 365 Small business feature online using trial subscription.

I'm able to create 'App Parts' using Office 365 Developer Site Subscription(by using 'NAPA' SharePoint Developer tool).

**Now I wanted to create SharePoint  'Custom WebPart' in Office 365 online without using Visual Studio 2010,2012,2013.**

Please Guide me on this by providing some reference links for creating "Custom WebParts" in Office 365 Online and how can i use created web parts.

Edited:

Are there any online tools or sharepoint apps like 'NAPA' available for develop custom Web Parts online?

Comment: Your SOL, for the most part.  O365, does not accept WSP's for installation.  You will have create AppParts, instead of WebParts.  If you want to do a Visual WebPart, you will need to shell out the money for Server 2012, Sharepoint 2013 Std, and SQL Server 2008r2.

Comment: Then that is my lack of knowledge, hope it works for ya.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sandbox solutions with SharePoint online.

But in SharePoint 2013 You can do many things just with Content Editor Web Part, javascript and REST services. And with search and display templates. 
We are using such technics with our on-premise SharePont 2013. And its cover all our needs. Client Object Model and REST services cover almost all SharPoint features. For content processing you can use Content by Search Web Part with display templates. For UI you can use javascript components like JQuery UI.

Comment: Thank You! @Nikolay Zainchkovskiy
you said that 'I can create Sandboxed Solutions online'. But before using sandboxed solutions in Office 365, i need to uploading sandboxed solution to site collection that should build the Windows Solution Package(.wsp) from Visual Studio right?

Comment: But my question is how can i create custom web parts using any online tools or Apps?
it can be either .dwp(web part) file or  any other formate that supports web parts.

Comment: You can create wsp package manually, like in this article: http://www.niteshluharuka.com/2011/11/how-to-create-a-wsp-file-manually. But if you can't use Visual Studio, I'm suggest you not to create custom web part, but use javascript CSOM and Content Editor Web Part.

Comment: So Finally we can't create Custom Web Parts in SharePoint Office 365 Online. Am i right? please correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: @SIRIGINEEDIRavi, you CAN create custom sandbox web parts in SharePoint Online. But it's easy to do with Visual Studio. It's seems strange to me to create custom web parts without VS. And in SharePoint Online you can do many thins with client side code only. You don't need access to SharePoint Server to use Content Editor Web Part. Just add this web part to any SharePoint page and add html and javascript content in it (or link to external html file in document library). You can use all power from js CSOM and SharePoint REST API.

Comment: Thank you! @Nikolay Zainchkovskiy for quick reply.